# Google doesn't see the friendly URLs

Tags: path-aliases, uri, xml-sitemap

Google doesn't see my SEO friendly URLs, while the other search engines can.

The browsers (IE, Chrome, FF), the RSS, the TweetFeed everything can see the SEO friendly URLs; in the XML sitemap, the system also see them.
Google Webmaster, and Google Analytics also see the friendly URLs, but if I search on my site via Google ("site:mywebsitedomain"), it can see only the node system URLs (e.g. mysite.com/node/6574).

Before the system update, it was working well. My host supports friendly URLs; I have installed the PathAuto, and the Global Redirect modules; clean URLs are enable.

Why doesn't Google see the SEO friendly URLs I set for the site?

Comment: Check your sitemap (usually example.com/sitemap.xml)
Does it contain seo urls or normal urls (eg node/XX) ?

Comment: First generate xml sitemap with proper URLs and log in to Google Webmaster Tools, Submit your sitemap there. It will start indexing and you can see the results in 1 or 2 weeks.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the site map there are only the friendly URL-s and I also uploaded to the Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Google will only index one version of the same page. It sounds like you have multiple URL's showing the same page. This is called *dublicated content*. Google will just choose one of the URL's, in your case, the wrong one.

When you enter mysite.com/node/6574 are you redirected to the friendly url? If not, then the GlobalRedirect module is not active or there is no aliases for the URL.

So make sure it's active and in `admin/config/system/globalredirect` check *Deslash* and *Non-clean to Clean* to further minimize dublicated content.

Also make sure that all internal and external links are pointing to your clean url's.

If the above is done, you just need to wait. Be patience - it can take weeks/months.

And forget about the sitemap. The important part is your internal links.

Comment: If I clikc on the node/6574 url I'm going to be redirected to the friendly url.
The Deslash and Non-clean to Clean options are checked.
I'm using everywhere I can my clean URLs.
Am I going back very much beacuse of this in the google? My titles and descriptions, keywords, etc. are ok, and google see them.

Comment: Ok. In time Google will begin using the URL redirected to. Whether this have had negative SEO effects is difficult to say. In the long run, it have no influence as long as there are no internal or external links pointing to the old URL's.